# Graphics drawing in a custom UIView don't work in the third view

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am trying to repurpose this [plotting widget](https://github.com/zerbfra/ZFPlotChart), and in particular I am trying to put 3 plots in one custom UIViewController. I am finding that the first two I process/add to my `self.view` are fine, but for the third view the following doesn't work

```
-(void) drawLineFrom:(CGPoint) start to: (CGPoint)end {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,end.x,end.y);

}


    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
    ...
           if([self.dictDispPoint count] > 0)
            {
                // remove loading animation
                [self stopLoading];

                float range = self.max-self.min;

                float intervalHlines = (self.chartHeight)/MIN(intervalLines, self.dictDispPoint.count - 1);    //5.0f;
                float intervalValues = range/MIN(intervalLines, self.dictDispPoint.count - 1);     //5.0f;

                // horizontal lines
                for(int i=intervalLines;i>0;i--)
                {

                    [self setContextWidth:0.5f andColor:linesColor];

                     CGPoint start = CGPointMake(self.leftMargin, (self.chartHeight+topMargin-i*intervalHlines-6));
                    CGPoint end = CGPointMake(self.chartWidth+self.leftMargin, (self.chartHeight+topMargin-i*intervalHlines-6));

                    // draw the line
                    [self drawLineFrom:start to:end];  // This line doesn't seem to run?!?

                    // draw prices on the axis
                    NSString *prezzoAsse = [self formatNumberWithUnits:(self.min+i*intervalValues)/valueDivider withFractionDigits:0];

                    CGPoint prezzoAssePoint = CGPointMake(self.leftMargin - [self sizeOfString:prezzoAsse withFont:systemFont].width - 5,(self.chartHeight+topMargin-i*intervalHlines-6));
                    [self drawString:prezzoAsse at:prezzoAssePoint withFont:systemFont andColor:linesColor];
                    [self endContext];

                }

         ...       
        }
```

In particular, I have verified that the `for loop` runs the requisite number of times and that all the variables have non-null sensible values. And the `drawString` function is working as expected, but somehow the horizontal lines I should be seeing never show up in the third instance of this custom view class.

- Printing all variable + line color...these are all non-null, sensible
- Changing the order of the graphs...it's always the 3rd graph (haven't tried more than 3) that has a problem
- Changing the data in the graph...the problem is there regardless of what data I supply to make the graph
- Cleaning the build, trying different iPhones in the simular...yup, this doesn't change the performance

I don't have much experience with `Quartz`.  Can anyone tell me if I am missing some traps for the unweary? Is there some threading problem when multiple views are draw simultaneously? What else could I try to trouble-shoot this?

---

Here is code showing how the plots are created and laid out on the screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Your recent runs";
    /********** Creating an area for the graph ***********/

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    self.width = screenWidth;
    self.height = screenRect.size.height;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.height*.15, screenWidth, self.height*.25);

    // initialization
    self.distancePlot = [[ZFPlotChart alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.distancePlot.units = self.distanceUnits;
    [self.view addSubview:self.distancePlot];

    frame.origin.y += self.height*.05 + frame.size.height;
    self.timePlot = [[ZFPlotChart alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.timePlot.units = self.timeUnits;
    [self.view addSubview:self.timePlot];

    //THIS IS THE PLOT FOR WHICH THE LINE-DRAWING CODE DOESN'T PRODUCE ANY VISIBLE LINES
    frame.origin.y += self.height*.05 + frame.size.height;
    self.ratePlot = [[ZFPlotChart alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.ratePlot.units = self.rateUnits;
    [self.view addSubview:self.ratePlot];

    self.distancePlot.alpha = 0;
    self.timePlot.alpha = 0;
    self.ratePlot.alpha = 0;

    CGFloat heightAdd = frame.size.height;
    frame = CGRectMake(0, self.height*.14, self.width, self.height*.03);

    ...some here creates UILabels above each plot....

    frame.origin.y += self.height*.05 + heightAdd;
    UILabel *rateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    rateLabel.text = @"Rate";
    rateLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkBlue];
    rateLabel.alpha = 0;
    rateLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:SYSTEM_FONT_TYPE size:SYSTEM_FONT_SIZE];
    rateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:rateLabel];

    // draw data
    [self.distancePlot createChartWith:self.distancePoints];
    [self.timePlot createChartWith:self.timePoints];
    [self.ratePlot createChartWith:self.ratePoints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.distancePlot.alpha = 1.0;
        self.timePlot.alpha = 1.0;
        self.ratePlot.alpha = 1.0;
        distanceLabel.alpha = 1.0;
        timeLabel.alpha = 1.0;
        rateLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    }];



}
```

Comment: If this code is working for all but the third graph then the problem isn't in these lines of code, but how your graphs are created and laid out on the screen.  Can you post any of that code?

Comment: @Putz1103 your suggested has been noted. I put the relevant view controller code in my edited question.

Comment: Have you tried setting a background color to all the graphs to make sure they are all drawn on the screen (they should be, I'm just checking)?  And with that code, if you make the time plot added to the view last it's the one that doesn't show, and the rateplot shows properly?

Comment: @Putz1103 yes I did set the background color to ensure entire view for each was on the screen. Also I am passing NSOrderedSets to the custom views for plotting. They are all interchangeable. I have tried sending data normally sent to a working view to the renegade third view, and this makes no difference, the third view still doesn't show the lines.

Comment: Have you tried setting up and adding the rateplot in the second position and having the timeplot in the third, then see which is not functional?  If it's still the rateplot then you are doing something different in that one than the others, if it's the timeplot then it's the location on screen that is a problem.

Comment: @Putz1103 I have tried changing both the order and location. It's always the third created one that has the problem regardless of location.